# Limitar valor de cookie a 30

Tags: php

Seguinte estou com o sistema para fazer um histórico em um site, ele salva os id das página que o usuário visitou, separando os id por virgula.

Seria possível limitar o valor a 30 ? exemplo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30".

E quando esse valor se exceder ele começar a atualizar os mais antigos substituindo os valores em ordem decrescente? exemplo: "1,2,3....29,53"

```
$id = $_COOKIE["id"];
$novoId = "$cont[id]";

if (!preg_match("/\b{$novoId}\b/", $id)) {
    setcookie("id", $id .= "{$novoId},");
}

$historico = explode(",", $id);

$histanime = array_filter($historico, function($value) {
    /* Retorna apenas os números inteiros */
    return is_numeric($value);
});


$ids5 = implode(",", $histanime) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `explode` + `array_slice` e finalizar com um `implode`.

```
$string = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30';
$novoId = 44;

$historico = array_filter(explode(',', $string), function($value) {
    return is_numeric($value);
});

if(in_array($novoId, $historico) === false){
    $historico[] = $novoId;
}

if(($quantidade = count($historico)) > 30){
    $historico = array_slice($historico, $quantidade - 30, 30);
}

$cookie = implode(',', $historico);

setcookie("id", $cookie);
```

Segundo o código original os `$novoId` é sempre inserido no final, portanto todos do começo são os mais antigos. Então continuamos acrescentando ele ao final, mas se houver mais de 30 elementos mantemos apenas os últimos 30.

Comment: se quiser levar em consideração o código completo, adicionei ele

Comment: @Gabriel, fiz as alterações.

Comment: Acrescentei if(($quantidade = count($historico)) > 30){
    $historico = array_slice($historico, $quantidade - 30, 30);
} ao código original e teve o mesmo efeito.